# Laravel: Uploading image

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

I want to see the picture that I uploaded in my database.

The problem is, I can't see the picture that I uploaded in my destination folder.

Can you tell me where does this path say and where does this store?

**Here's my controller:**

```
$display_photo = Input::file('display_photo');
$filename = $display_photo->getClientOriginalName();
$getphoto = $display_photo->move(public_path() .'/images/profile/'. Auth::user()->username . '/', $filename);

$user = User::find(Auth::user()->id);
$user->image =  $filename;
$user->save();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to check if there is a image file when you submit the form, what i suggest is that you do like this:

```
    if(Input::has('display_photo'))
  {
  $user = User::find(Auth::user()->id);
  $user->save();
  }
else{
  $user = User::find(Auth::user()->id);
  $user->image =  $filename;
  $user->save();
   }

   <form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" files="true">
```

But first make sure you have enabled file input on the form:

Answer (score -1):

Try like this:

```
$pathDir = 'uploads/documents'; // whatever directory you like
```

$getphoto = $display_photo->move($pathDir .'/images/profile/'. Auth::user()->username . '/', $filename);

```
<form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```